# When to use lock vs MemoryBarrier in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, locking, monitor, memory-barriers

In .NET the `lock` keyword is syntactic sugar around `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`, so you could say that this code

```
lock(locker)
{
  // Do something
}
```

is the same as

```
Monitor.Enter(locker);
try
{
  // Do Something
}
finally
{
  Monitor.Exit(locker);
}
```

However the .NET framework also includes the `MemoryBarrier` class which works in a similar way

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
//Do something
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
```

I am confused as when I would want to use `Thread.MemoryBarrier` over the `lock`/`Monitor` version? I am made even more confused by [a Threading Tutorial](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx) which states they function tthe same.

As far as I can see the visible difference is not needing a locking object, which I guess that using `Monitor` you could do something across threads where `MemoryBarrier` is on a single thread.

My gut is telling me that another key difference is `MemoryBarrier` is for variables only and not for methods.

Lastly this is not related to the existing question [When to use ‘volatile’ or ‘Thread.MemoryBarrier()’ in threadsafe locking code? (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330590/when-to-use-volatile-or-thread-memorybarrier-in-threadsafe-locking-code-c), as that is focusing on the `volatile` keyword which I understand its usage of.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In my view you should almost *never* use `Thread.MemoryBarrier`. This is used for *lock-free* code - making sure that changes made on one thread are visible to another without incurring the cost of a lock. It does *not* control thread synchronization, unlike `lock`. I don't see where in Joe's tutorial he says that `MemoryBarrier` "functions the same" as `lock`. Could you explain where exactly you're getting that impression from?

In my view, low level lock-free code is too difficult for almost anyone other than developers whose main proficiency is concurrency. If I want to write some lock-free code, I'll use higher level building blocks *built* by those developers (such as Parallel Extensions in .NET 4.0) rather than trying to roll my own.

Just as an example, I recently had my eyes opened to the precise meaning of `volatile` which *isn't* "always read from main memory, always write directly to main memory". (My own threading tutorial still has that explanation at the moment - something I need to fix at some point.) [It's far more subtle than that](http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/11/10/clr-20-memory-model/). This means that *some* of my previous uses of `volatile` may well be incorrect.

Comment: In Joe's tutorial (on the page I link to) search for 'Memory barriers and locking' there is a short paragraph which states they are equivalent "if we ignore a lock’s mutual exclusion guarantee".

Comment: However ignoring the mutual exclusion makes the comparison kind of pointless since that is an integral component of the locks

Comment: @Grizzly: The comparison isn't pointless - it's useful in terms of *fences*. But that's not the same as saying the two things "function the same" - because the mutual exclusion guarantee is the main point of locking.

Comment: [Link](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,dd3aff8a-7f8d-4de6-a2e7-d199662b68f4.aspx) no longer works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, Joe Duffy's blog has been a pain in various ways. Will see if I can find a replacement.