# Thread.MemoryBarrier and lock difference for a simple property

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

For the following scenario, **is there any difference** regarding thread-safeness, result and performance between using `MemoryBarrier`

```
private SomeType field;

public SomeType Property
{
    get
    {
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        SomeType result = field;
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        field = value;
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    }
}
```

and `lock` statement (`Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`)

```
private SomeType field;
private readonly object syncLock = new object();

public SomeType Property
{
    get
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            return field;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Because reference assignment is atomic so I think that in this scenarios we do need any locking mechanism.

**Performance**
The MemeoryBarrier is about 2x faster than lock implementation for Release. Here are my test results:

```
Lock
Normaly: 5397 ms
Passed as interface: 5431 ms

Double Barrier
Normaly: 2786 ms
Passed as interface: 3754 ms

volatile
Normaly: 250 ms
Passed as interface: 668 ms

Volatile Read/Write
Normaly: 253 ms
Passed as interface: 697 ms

ReaderWriterLockSlim
Normaly: 9272 ms
Passed as interface: 10040 ms

Single Barrier: freshness of Property
Normaly: 1491 ms
Passed as interface: 2510 ms

Single Barrier: other not reodering
Normaly: 1477 ms
Passed as interface: 2275 ms
```

Here is how I tested it in LINQPad (with optimization set in Preferences):

```
void Main()
{   
    "Lock".Dump();
    string temp;
    var a = new A();
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        temp = a.Property;
        a.Property = temp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Normaly: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Test(a);

    "Double Barrier".Dump();
    var b = new B();
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        temp = b.Property;
        b.Property = temp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Normaly: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Test(b);

    "volatile".Dump();
    var c = new C();
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        temp = c.Property;
        c.Property = temp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Normaly: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Test(c);

    "Volatile Read/Write".Dump();
    var d = new D();
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        temp = d.Property;
        d.Property = temp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Normaly: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Test(d);

    "ReaderWriterLockSlim".Dump();
    var e = new E();
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        temp = e.Property;
        e.Property = temp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Normaly: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Test(e);

    "Single Barrier: freshness of Property".Dump();
    var f = new F();
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        temp = f.Property;
        f.Property = temp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Normaly: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Test(f);

    "Single Barrier: other not reodering".Dump();
    var g = new G();
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        temp = g.Property;
        g.Property = temp;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Normaly: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    Test(g);
}

void Test(I a)
{
    string temp;
    var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
    {
        temp = a.Property;
        a.Property = temp;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Passed as interface: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms\n");
}

interface I
{
    string Property { get; set; }
}

class A : I
{
    private string field;
    private readonly object syncLock = new object();

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                return field;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (syncLock)
            {
                field = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

class B : I
{
    private string field;

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            string result = field;
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            field = value;
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        }
    }
}

class C : I
{
    private volatile string field;

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            return field;
        }
        set
        {
            field = value;
        }
    }
}

class D : I
{
    private string field;

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            return Volatile.Read(ref field);
        }
        set
        {
            Volatile.Write(ref field, value);
        }
    }
}

class E : I
{
    private string field;
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            locker.EnterReadLock();
            string result = field;
            locker.ExitReadLock();
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            locker.EnterReadLock();
            field = value;
            locker.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
}

class F : I
{
    private string field;

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            return field;
        }
        set
        {
            field = value;
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        }
    }
}

class G : I
{
    private string field;

    public string Property
    {
        get
        {
            string result = field;
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            field = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you already read this article? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005211/when-to-use-lock-vs-memorybarrier-in-net

Comment: Yes I did. But reference assigning in .NET is atomic so in my opinion it does not need a locking mechanism...

Comment: This is a very useful book / series to understand threading - http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx I wholly recommend you read that before you attempt any "clever tricks" :) He does describe how memory barriers work, too.  
Atomic isn't enough on a multi-core / multi-processor system. The new (or old) value might be stored in a register, or in a cache. That's why you need the memory barriers. Instruction reordering along with method inlining will probably also be an issue.

Comment: I was reading it a few times :) It is really great! 

Caching - this is why I added the Thread.MemoryBarrier() beacuse: "The simplest kind of memory barrier is a full memory barrier (full fence) which prevents any kind of instruction reordering or caching around that fence."

Comment: Locks are hard enough to understand properly already. The performance difference between a lock and a (full) memory barrier is smaller and smaller, so why add to complexity? And if you don't want a lock, why not use `Interlocked.Exchange` instead? It does pretty much the same thing as your barriers, but is easier to read (shows the semantics better). Now, half-fences are faster again (about a factor of two), but writing those correctly is double the pain.

Comment: How I would use `Interlocked` to get the property value? Could you write the code in the answer? In my opinion half-fences might not work here because it could reorder the writes and reads. The example in the book explains it.

Comment: Yeah, that's getting to the very weird territory. I believe you wouldn't need a memory barrier around the read at all, since you already have a full fence around the write (which *should* invalidate the cache of the other cores / processors - probably not the registers, though). But those are my speculations based on things I still don't fully understand. The JIT compiler does a lot of funny stuff, and the CPU itself uses out-of-order execution.

Comment: @Luaan: Putting a full fence around the write and leaving the read unlocked is not enough. I am in the middle of writing a pair of articles on this subject. The first is here: http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/  The second will go up on the 26th of March 2014.

Comment: @EricLippert That's a great article, thanks. But unless locking around multiple operations on the property, the `Interlocked`-on-write, naked-on-read would still be just as unsafe as full locks on `set` and `get`, right? Is there anything general we can actually say about the safety if we don't know the code around the property accesses?

Comment: @Luaan: Indeed, it is very hard to reason about the correctness of the program without knowing what the rest of the code is and what the program invariants are. This is why low-lock coding is so difficult; you really can't analyze it in isolation.  Just because every brick is solid doesn't mean that the house isn't hollow.

Comment: Question?  Why do you not test for if(field == value) return;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> is there any difference regarding thread-safeness?

Both ensure that appropriate barriers are set up around the read and write.

> result?

In both cases two threads can race to write a value.  However, reads and writes cannot move forwards or backwards in time past either the lock or the full fences.

> performance?

You've written the code both ways. **Now run it**.  If you want to know which is faster, run it and find out! If you have two horses and you want to know which is faster, race them. Don't ask strangers on the Internet which horse they think is faster.

That said, a better technique is **set a performance goal**, write the code to be clearly correct, and then test to see if you met your goal. If you did, don't waste your valuable time trying to optimize further code that is already fast enough; spend it optimizing something else that isn't fast enough.

A question you didn't ask:

> What would you do?

I'd not write a multithreaded program, that's what I'd do. I'd use processes as my unit of concurrency if I had to.

If I had to write a multithreaded program then I would use the highest-level tool available. I'd use the Task Parallel Library, I'd use async-await, I'd use `Lazy<T>` and so on. I'd avoid shared memory; I'd treat threads as lightweight processes that returned a value asynchronously.

If I had to write a shared-memory multithreaded program then I would **lock everything, all the time**. We routinely write programs these days that fetch a billion bytes of video over a satellite link and send it to a phone. Twenty nanoseconds spent taking a lock isn't going to kill you.

I am not smart enough to try to write low-lock code, so I wouldn't do that at all. If I had to then **I would use that low-lock code to build a higher-level abstraction** and use that abstraction. Fortunately I don't have to because someone already has built the abstractions I need.

Comment: Thanks for you the answer! I wanted to improve my knowledge regarding multithreading. I would post the performance test result when I will have time to make some.

Comment: I made another question concerning "What would you do": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465853/high-performance-caching . Thanks for helping me in this one!

Answer (score 1):

As long as the variable in question is one of the limited set of variables that can be fetched/set atomically (i.e. reference types), then yes, the two solutions are applying the same thread-related constraints.

That said, I would honestly expect the `MemoryBarrier` solution to perform *worse* than a lock.  Accessing an uncontested `lock` block is *very* fast.  It has been optimized specifically for that case.  On the other hand, introducing a memory barrier, which affects not only the access to *that one variable*, as is the case for a `lock`, but *all memory*, could very easily have significant negative performance implications throughout other aspects of the application.  You would of course need to do some testing to be sure, (of your real applications, because testing these two in isolation isn't going to reveal the fact that the memory barrier is forcing all of the rest of the application's memory to be synchronized, not just this one variable).

Comment: Are you sure about the performance? The `lock` also generates a fence. See: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx. Are you sure that lock makes a fence for *only one variable*? Do you have any resource?

Comment: @Pellared No, I'm not sure, which is why I specifically said, "I would expect" and "you would of course need to do some testing to be sure".  The `lock` is simply determining how the operations relating to the `lock` can be reordered.  It doesn't consider operations *not* in the `lock`.  The fact that it doesn't is what brings up [this issue](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/)

Comment: `MemoryBarrier` is also about operation ordering. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Pellared: To clarify Servy's answer: in *practice* a lock creates fences that ensure that all reads on the thread do not move backwards in time past the beginning of the lock and all writes do not move forwards in time past the end of the lock. Section 3.10 of the specification calls out the slightly weaker *guarantees* that an implementation of C# must provide. In two weeks I'll be doing a blog article on how volatile reads and writes can be re-ordered and how that can be prevented with locks; see my blog for details.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thank you. To clarify: Cory Nelson answer is incorrect, yes? Am I also correct that the implementation cannot be implemented using `Interlocked` as Luaan commented my question?

Comment: @Pellared: Luaan's comment to Cory Nelson's answer is germane. The fence introduced by Volatile.Read / Write is weaker than the full fences you have introduced.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference as far as thread safety goes. However, I would prefer:

```
private SomeType field

public SomeType Property
{
    get
    {
        return Volatile.Read(ref field);
    }
    set
    {
        Volatile.Write(ref field, value);
    }
}
```

Or,

```
private volatile SomeType field

public SomeType Property
{
    get
    {
        return field;
    }
    set
    {
        field = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but if you write first, and then read, the instructions can be swapped by the compiler - there is no barrier between the write and read. I'm not sure if this can actually happen if you only use a single field in both the read and write. Also, your two examples aren't actually the same (`Volatile.XXX` does `Thread.MemoryBarrier`). See http://joeduffyblog.com/2008/06/13/volatile-reads-and-writes-and-timeliness/ for more DF-style FUN.

Comment: @Luaan: Even in the version with the lock, two threads can race to determine whether a read or a write happens first. How is that different here? You are right to note that volatile reads and writes can be re-ordered but coming up with an actual scenario that shows the bad behaviour can be tricky.

Comment: @EricLippert You're right, the code is actually too simple to have any difference. I've been thinking about what would happen if this kind of thing was used as part of some non-blocking synchronization attempt. Overall, the code seems like a bad idea. What is it really trying to accomplish, as part of the bigger picture? If there's a need for synchronization as part of some larger operation, it shouldn't be done inside the property. It appears to be giving some guarantees, but there really aren't any useful guarantees through this, are there?