# High performance caching

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

The following code is supposed to cache the last read. The `LastValueCache` is a cache that can be accessed by many threads (this is why I use the shared-memory). It is OK for me to have race conditions but I want that other threads would see the changed `LastValueCache`.

```
class Repository
{
    public Item LastValueCache
    {
        get
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            SomeType result = field;
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
            field = value;
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        }
    }

    public void Save(Item item)
    {
        SaveToDatabase(item);
        Item cached = LastValueCache;
        if (cached == null || item.Stamp > cached.Stamp)
        {
            LastValueCache = item;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(Timestamp stamp)
    {
        RemoveFromDatabase(item);
        Item cached = LastValueCache;
        if (cached != null && cached.Stamp == item.Stamp)
        {
            LastValueCache = null;
        }
    }

    public Item Get(Timestamp stamp)
    {
        Item cached = LastValueCache;
        if (cached != null && cached.Stamp == stamp)
        {
            return cached;
        }

        return GetFromDatabase(stamp);
    }
}
```

The `Repository` object is used by many threads. I do not want to use locking because it would affect performance which in my case is more important than data consistency. The question is **what smallest synchronizing mechanism that will fit my need?** Maybe `volatile` or single `MemoryBarrier` in `get` and `set` would be enough?

Comment: Note, that a lock is a pretty cheap primitive if uncontended. Your critical section is tiny (a dozen instructions or so). This should cost about 2 interlocked operations.; Apart from that, I think volatile should do the trick. But I'm no expert on that. The double memory barriers you are using right now should work, too.

Comment: I don't understand your requirements. If race conditions are OK, then the value returned by LastValueCache could easily be invalid. For example, someone calls remove on the current value, remove sees an older cache value than the current, doesn't set the cache to null, and then boom, LastCacheValue is referring to a removed item.

Comment: It is okey for me. But I do not want that this state would last forever. That said when I finally set the `LastValueCache` I want that other thread could refresh its references.

Comment: @Pellared: But it would be forever (at least, until the next Save with a newer timestamp, assuming your timestamps are always increasing).

Comment: @Cameron And now I do not understand you unfortunately. Time goes as follows: Thread 1-`RemoveFromDatabase`, Thread 2-`Get` (gets the removed value from the cache), Thread 1-`LastValueCache = null`; Thread 2-`Get` (now it gets the value from the database).

Comment: You're losing updates here in a race condition (I.e. the cache never showing the latest value according to timestamp ordering but an older one)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here's one scenario where the LastCachedValue can become invalid: Thread 1 calls Save, and is about to set LastCachedValue after updating the DB. Thread 2 then calls Get on the same item -- LastCachedValue is still null, but it gets the item from the DB. Thread 2 then calls Remove on the item. Thread 1 then finally resumes and sets the LastCacheValue to the item that is no longer in the DB. Chaos ensues :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is stupid you don't need to vote me down.
Just tell me and I will delete.
But I am not following this logic.

```
public void Save(Item item)
{
    SaveToDatabase(item);
    Item cached = LastValueCache;
    if (cached == null || item.Stamp > cached.Stamp)
    {
        LastValueCache = item;
    }
}
```

You are worried about memory milliseconds but you are waiting on a write to the database before you update the cache.
Based on the public Item Get stamp is a key.

Lets assume a db write is 20 ms
A db read is 10 ms
Cache get and cache set are each 2 ms

public void Save(Item item)
SaveToDatabase(item);  20 ms
Item cached = LastValueCache; 2 ms
if (cached == null || item.Stamp > cached.Stamp)  1 ms
LastValueCache = item;  2 ms

During that 23 ms prior to the LastValueCache = item; any call to public Item Get(Timestamp stamp) is going to hit the DataBase and not the cache.

During the 23 ms prior to the LastValueCache = item; any call to public Item LastValueCache 
get is going to get a value that is stale by up 23 ms. 
The stated objective is for other threads to see LastValueCache - but the are seeing a stale LastValueCache.

Same thing with Remove.
You are going to have several hits to the database you could have avoided.

What are you trying to achieve?
Have you profiled this?

My bet is the bottle neck is the calls to the database.
A database call is 1000x longer than the difference between a lock and MemoryBarrier.

```
public void Save(Item item)
{   
   // add logic that the prior asynchonous call to SaveToDatabase is complete
   // if not wait for it to complete 
   // LastValueCache will possible be replaced so you need last item in the database 
   // the time for a lock is not really a factor as it will be faster than the prior update 
   Item cached = LastValueCache;
   if (cached == null || item.Stamp > cached.Stamp)
   {
       LastValueCache = item;
   }
   // make the next a task or background so it does not block    
   SaveToDatabase(item);
}
```

Could even change the logic to only wait for prior call if you setting LastValueCache = item;
But you need to throttle the database somehow

The next step would be to cache the last X and use that in Item Get(Timestamp stamp)
The database are calls are what you need to optimize
Again you need to profile

After that the logic would get more complex but feed the database calls to a BlockingCollection.  Would need to be sure the last X cache is bigger than the BlockingCollections size. If not block and wait for the BC to clear.  And you would need to use the same BC for insert and delete so they are processed in order.  Could get smart enough that you just don't insert a records that has a delete.   And don't just insert or delete a single record at a time.

Comment: Thanks, it is a very good comment. My case is more complex in reality... I will try to check it and think the second time (and maybe revert the old locks).

Comment: And I would consider performing the database update asynchronous.  And rather than just caching the last then cache then use a concurrent collection to save the last x.  The database is your bottleneck.  I would post an example of how but did not even get a +1.

Comment: I thought the same thing when I saw your code - performance issues and lockless algorithms only matter when there's no I/O on your critical path. Talk to a database and you may as well go get a coffee while you're at it. Or make it async. Even if it is async, the fact the locks are apparently an issue indicates you must be accessing this data a hell of a lot. Can the DB keep up?

Answer (score 3):

I implemented a thread safe pseudo LRU designed for concurrent workloads: ConcurrentLru. Performance is very close to ConcurrentDictionary, ~10x faster than MemoryCache and hit rate is better than a conventional LRU. Full analysis provided in the github link below.

Usage looks like this:

```
int capacity = 666;
var lru = new ConcurrentLru<int, SomeItem>(capacity);

var value = lru.GetOrAdd(1, (k) => new SomeItem(k));
```

GitHub: https://github.com/bitfaster/BitFaster.Caching

```
Install-Package BitFaster.Caching
```

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` should be sufficient and most performant for your case. There are potential scenarios where `volatile` alone is not sufficient for ensuring the read gets the most up-to-date value, but in this case, I don't think it would be an important factor. See the "the volatile keyword" section of [this awesome article by Joe Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative use may be the `ReaderWriterLockSlim` class to enable thread synchronization for reader/writer scenarios like yours.

```
    ReaderWriterLockSlim _rw = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    get
    {
        _rw.EnterReadLock();
        SomeType result = field;
        _rw.ExitReadLock();
        return result;
    }
    set
    {
        _rw.EnterWriteLock();
        field = value;
        _rw.ExitWriteLock();
    }
```

This is an efficent implementation for Reader/Writer synchronization. This [blog entry](http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer/) of Eric Lippert may be interessting for you.

Another intersting Option may be the `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` class that creates two TaskScheduler for Tasks, wich can be splitted in 'Task with read access' (Concurrent) and 'Tasks with write access' (Exclusive).

More information about this can found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: This would be a lot slower. Assigning a reference is atomic so locking the property gives us only an overhead. Moreover I do not want any locking as I already mentioned in the question. The previous implementation had used a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` around the methods (ReadLock for Get, WriteLock for Save and Delete) but it was to slow.

Comment: Did you read the article by Eric Lippert? But it's no problem if you think that your Code is threadsafe...

Comment: Yes I did. Moreover - he answered my other question concerning it - check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457501/thread-memorybarrier-and-lock-difference-for-a-simple-property

Comment: I prefer locking, but if you need realy highspeeed the lock is not cheap enough. May the ConcurrentExclusiveScheduslerPair a solution for the Layer above. This is only a solution if this code is only used and controlled by your software.

Comment: Reader-writer locks are quite a bit slower unless you really have a *lot* of readers and very few writers.