# Duplicate entries on server response .net

Tags: c#, service, windows-services, locking, boolean

## Scenario

One windows service polls a url every two minutes to retrieve certain data.

If any data has been added since the previous call, the data is retrieved and stored otherwise the loop carries on.

## Issue

Sometimes a request takes more than two minutes to return a response.

When this happens, the next request is still made and finds new data, since the previous request hasn't return a response yet

This results in duplicate entries when the data is stored.

## What I've tried

I tried to handle that by using a boolean like so:

```
Boolean InProgress = true;
foreach (var item in Lists)
{ 
\\Make a request and return new data (if any)
InProgress = false;
if (InProgress = false)
  {
  \\Store new data
  }
}
```

This doesn't solve the issue. I believe I'm using the boolean in wrong place, but I'm not sure where it should.

This is the loop that makes the request and store the data

```
void serviceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Data getCredentials = new Data();
            DataTable credentials = getCredentials.loadCredentials();
            Boolean InProgress = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < credentials.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (credentials != null)
                {
                    var PBranchID = (int)credentials.Rows[i]["PortalBranchID"];
                    var negRef = (int)credentials.Rows[i]["NegotiatorRef"];
                    var Username = credentials.Rows[i]["Username"].ToString();
                    var Password = credentials.Rows[i]["Password"].ToString();
                    var Domain = credentials.Rows[i]["Domain"].ToString();
                    var FooCompanyBaseUrl = "https://" + Domain + ".FooCompany.com/";

                    Data getCalls = new Data();
                    DataTable calls = getCalls.loadCalls(PBranchID);

                    //If it's not the first call
                    if (calls != null && calls.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        //Makes a call
                        DateTime CreatedSince = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)calls.Rows[0]["LastSuccessOn"], DateTimeKind.Local);
                        string IssueListUrl = FooCompany.WebApi.V2.URLs.Issues(BaseUrl, null, CreatedSince.ToUniversalTime(), null);
                        FooCompany.WebApi.V2.DTO.PrevNextPagedList resultIssueList;

                        resultIssueList = FooCompany.WebApi.Client.Helper.Utils.Getter<Foocompany.WebApi.V2.DTO.PrevNextPagedList>(IssueListUrl, Username, Password);
                        InProgress = false;
                        if (InProgress == false)
                        {
                            if (resultIssueList.Items.Count > 0)
                            {
                                //If call returns new issues, save call
                                Data saveCalls = new Data();
                                saveCalls.saveCalls(PBranchID);

                                foreach (var item in resultIssueList.Items)
                                {
                                    var Issue = FooCompany.WebApi.Client.Helper.Utils.Getter<FooCompany.WebApi.V2.DTO.Issue>(item, Username, Password);

                                    string TenantSurname = Issue.Surname;
                                    string TenantEmail = Issue.EmailAddress;
                                    Data tenants = new Data();
                                    int tenantPropRef = Convert.ToInt32(tenants.loadTenantPropRef(PBranchID, TenantSurname, TenantEmail));
                                    Data Properties = new Data();
                                    DataTable propAddress = Properties.loadPropAddress(PBranchID, tenantPropRef);
                                    var Address1 = propAddress.Rows[0]["Address1"];
                                    var Address2 = propAddress.Rows[0]["Address2"];
                                    var AddressFolder = Address1 + "," + Address2;
                                    if (!Directory.Exists("path"))
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory("path");
                                    }
                                    string ReportPDFDestination = "path";

                                    if (File.Exists(ReportPDFDestination))
                                    {
                                        File.Delete(ReportPDFDestination);
                                    }
                                    FooCompany.WebApi.Client.Helper.Utils.DownloadFileAuthenticated(FooCompany.WebApi.V2.URLs.IssueReport(BaseUrl, Issue.Id), Username, Password, ReportPDFDestination);


                                    //Store data 

                                }
                                IssueListUrl = resultIssueList.NextURL;

                            }
                        }

                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //write to log
        }
    }
```

## Question

I'm sure there is a better way than a boolean.

Could anyone advice a different method to handle the issue properly?
Thanks.

## Solution

I ended up using a combination of both Thomas and Mason suggestions. I wrapped a lock statement around the main function of my windows service and used a boolean inside the function section that makes the call to the remote server.
Tested many times and it's error free.

Comment: We need to see your code that calls this code in order to give you a good response.

Comment: I use threads, but I keep track of the state in a flag and I don't allow it to call again until the flag is reset to zero, or exceeds some reasonable time.

Comment: @mason I've added the code that makes the call

Comment: @dura Does adding synchronisation solved your problem?

Comment: You added the code that actually retrieves the data, but that's not really relevant. We need to see what calls the first code you posted. By the way, that first block, you're setting a Boolean to false, then testing to see if it's false right afterwards. It will **always** be false. And you need to use `==` to test for equality. `=` is the assignment operator.

Comment: thanks Mason. I will post the other section of code. Regarding the boolean: it is set to true when I declare it.

Comment: @Mason did you have a chance to check the new section I posted?

Comment: Yes, and it suffers from the *exact same problem I mentioned before*. You set InProgress to false, and directly afterwards you check to see if it's false. Of course it's false. It will always be false when you get to that if statement since you're setting it to false right before you get to it.

Comment: I feel I'm missing something but that's what I want: I want the code inside the if statement to be executed only when inprogress is false.

Comment: Would it solve my problem if I set the boolean to true at the end of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to have a problem of synchronisation, just surround the code that iterate though the List with a lock, and you will be fine.

```
public class MyClass{
private readonly object internalLock= new object();
private bool AlreadyRunning { get;  set; }
void serviceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(AlreadyRunning){
        return;
    }

    try{
        lock(internalLock){     
            Thread.MemoryBarrier();

            if(AlreadyRunning){
                return;
            }
            AlreadyRunning = true;

            ...Do all the things...
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ..Exception handling
    }
    finally
    {
        AlreadyRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The line that makes the request needs to be inside the loop. So i'm not sure about locking the code inside it.

Comment: @dura You need to give us more code so. You seems to have a synchronisation issue. Now, you can try to find it yourself or give us more code!

Comment: Sorry I was having a nightmare to delete the sensitive info from the code. But I've added it now.

Comment: In the meantime I will try the lock solution.

Comment: Can you confirm that your problem is that you have several `ReportPDFDestination` generated for the same Issue?

Comment: That's correct. I don't however get two files for the same issue because it overwrites the old one if it's the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54803/discussion-between-thomas-and-dura).

Comment: I'm still not sure about the code you posted. I've read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005211/when-to-use-lock-vs-memorybarrier-in-net and it looks like using a memory barrier as well as a lock is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool InProgress=false;

void serviceTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
    if(!InProgress)
        {
        InProgress=true;
        //retrieve data
        InProgress=false;
        }
    }
```

Your InProgress variable needs to be declared outside the event handler. When you enter the method, check to see if it's already running. If it is, then we do nothing. If it's not running, then we say it's running, retrieve our data, then reset our flag to say we've finished running.

You'll probably need to add appropriate locks for thread safety, similar to Thomas's answer.

Comment: thanks that's very clear. I'll wait to mark my answer to see which one I end up using.

Comment: Carefull,if an exception is thrown, then you will stop retieving data as `InProgress` will stay `false`. a try/catch/finally is important I think.

Comment: @Mason thanks very much for your time. I've marked Thomas' as the answer because he took some extra time on the chat to advise me (and he also has less votes than you)