# Multithreading - Understanding memory barriers and volatile

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, clr, memory-barriers

I'm studying c# threading following famous 'C# in a Nutshell' and during investigation of Thread.MemoryBarrier() phenomena, I was scared to death when I stumbled upon Brian's example on [Why we need Thread.MemoryBarrier()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556351/why-we-need-thread-memorybarrier).

I'm having i-7 8700K processor and 4.6.1 .NET and I managed to reproduce the problem (program never ends) even with following changes in program:

```
class Program
{
    static bool stop = false;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread begin");
            bool toggle = false;
            //while (true)
            while (!stop) 
            {
                if (stop)
                {
                    break;
                }
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Thread end");
        });
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        stop = true;
        Console.WriteLine($"Stop flag set. Waiting for thread to end...");
        t.Join();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

So, even with "if (stop)" check, problem reproduces and I understand why. When I place "Thread.MemoryBarrier()" before that check problem doesn't reproduce (at least I failed to reproduce it) and I understand why. But what I don't understand is why problem is not reproducing anymore when I change while condition and put "while (true)" instead of "while (!stop)"? Does it have something to do with special treatment of "while (true)" statement?

Answer (score 1):

> why problem is not reproducing anymore when I change while condition and put "while (true)" instead of "while (!stop)"?

The behavior depends on several factors like: hardware, operating system, runtime environment... For example, on my machine the problem is not reproduced even with your original code with `while (!stop)`. And I believe, the problem can be reproduced with `while (true)` on another environment.

Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet state that we don't need to use such low-level techniques like `Thread.MemoryBarrier` unless we are real experts in that area ([link#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2005237/4242590) and [link#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2529773/4242590)). Probably, you should consider to use `volatile` keyword with `stop` declaration which expresses your intention more explicitly and lets you not to use `Thread.MemoryBarrier`. Or even consider use of `Task` with `CancellationToken` to have ability to cancel `Task`.

Looking to your username maybe it worth to note that Eric Lippert and Jon Skeet regarding `.net` are like Gandalf regarding magic

**Update**

Read Eric Lippert's comments below. Don't use `volatile` as well as `Thread.MemoryBarrier` until you *really* need it.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out; a couple fun facts for you. First, *I am not knowledgable enough to know when to use volatile vs memory barrier and so on*. I'm not an expert in this area; what I am an expert on is *knowing that it is too complicated for me to get it right*.  That's why I tell people to just take out a lock. If your application needs performance such that an uncontended lock is too expensive, you should hire an expert on nano-scale optimizations. Second, my alias on Commodore 64 BBS's was "Radagast". :-)

Comment: Thanks, especially for the second fact. I was almost accurate about this:) I've read your [article about volatility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/) and it is clear that `volatile` is not so obvious for us (non experts in this area). So do you recommend not to use `volatile` as I suggested in the answer even in this basic case?

Comment: My recommendation is: if you use `volatile` it is because you are doing something super dangerous: modifying memory on two threads without a lock. You've got a kitchen full of cooks and you're trying to juggle their knives while they're using them; the slightest mistake and someone is going to get cut. You had better know exactly why `volatile` is correct and what the implications are on correctness and performance. But I suspect many people use volatile because someone on the internet told them that if they do, their threading performance problems will vanish at no cost.

Comment: Hi, Albert. Thank you for your response. And I also thank Eric for honest and practical advice.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing special about `while (true)`.

Your detailed answer is described here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj863136.aspx

Comment: In the current state this is a **link-only answer**, which we want to avoid on Stack Overflow. Please, add some details from the referenced page into the answer post.

Comment: Nick, thank you. Any good link where I can learn new stuff is acceptable to me.