# Volatile and Thread.MemoryBarrier in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, nonblocking, volatile, memory-barriers

To implement a **lock free code** for multithreading application I used `volatile` variables,
**Theoretically**: The `volatile` keyword is simply used to make sure that all threads see the most updated value of a volatile variable; so if thread `A` updates the variable value and thread `B` read that variable just after that update is happened it will see the most updated value that written recently from thread A.
As I read in a **C# 4.0 in a Nutshell** book that 
this is **incorrect** because

> applying volatile doesn’t prevent a write followed by a read from being swapped.

Could this problem being solved by putting `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` before every get of the `volatile` variable like:

```
private volatile bool _foo = false;

private void A()
{
    //…
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    if (_foo)
    {
        //do somthing
    }
}

private void B()
{
    //…
    _foo = true;
    //…
}
```

And if this solves the problem; consider we have a while loop that depend on that value at one of its conditions; is putting `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` before the while loop is a correct way to fix the issue? example:

```
private void A()
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    while (_someOtherConditions && _foo)
    {
        // do somthing.
    }
}
```

To be more accurate I want the `_foo` variable to give its most fresh value when any thread asking for it at any time; so if inserting `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` before calling the variable fixes the issue then could I use `Foo` property instead of `_foo` and do a `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` within the get of that property Like:

```
Foo
{
    get 
    {
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
        return _foo;
    }
    set
    {
        _foo = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330590/when-to-use-volatile-or-thread-memorybarrier-in-threadsafe-locking-code-c

Comment: @Aron; no it is not duplicate; this is another question.

Comment: @Jalal Are you trying to solve a problem using this approach volatile/memorybarrier or are you ok with any approach which solves your problem?

Comment: @Aron; I am trying to solve this problem using volatile/memorybarrier approach.

Comment: Don't confuse volatile with lock free code. Volatile doesn't in any case make your code thread safe.

Comment: what version of .net are you using.

Comment: @Jalal this is an indepth topic, check this out...http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx specifically the Full Fences section to get an understanding of what the MemoryBarrier provides and how it is replicated when using lock.

Comment: @Aaron: I already checked it "Threading/part4.aspx" it is at the same book "C# 4.0 in a Nutshell".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "C# In a Nutshell" is correct, but its statement is moot.  Why?

- A 'write' followed by a 'read', withot 'volatile', is guaranteed to occur in program-order anyway *if it effects logic* within a single thread
- The 'write' before a 'read' in a multi-threaded program is **utterly pointless** to worry about in your example.

Let's clarify.  Take your original code:

```
private void A() 
{ 
    //… 
    if (_foo) 
    { 
        //do something 
    } 
}
```

What happens if the thread scheduler has already checked the `_foo` variable, but it gets suspended just before the `//do something` comment?  Well, at that point your other thread could change the value of `_foo`, which means that all your volatiles and Thread.MemoryBarriers counted for nothing!!!  If it is absolutely essential that the `do_something` be avoided if the value of `_foo` is false, then you have no choice but to use a lock.

However, if it is ok for the `do something` to be executing when suddenly `_foo` becomes false, then it means the volatile keyword was more than enough for your needs.

To be clear: all the responders who are telling you to use a memory barrier are incorrect or are providing overkill.

Comment: thanks for your response; 
In my case I want to avoid do_something to be executed if the  _foo was true as much as possible, but it is **not deadly critical**; but if I could  make it more accurate with MemoryBarrier then **why not** use it with the volatile..  

If the thread schedule suspend the thread after the _foo check "witch is possible" then the do_somthing will execute but at least we **reduce chances** that the _foo will be false at that time right?

Comment: @Jalal: the `volatile` declaration already gaurantees, all by itself, that the variable will not be stored in a CPU register.  It gaurantees direct memory reads and writes (which invalidates the cache of other processors on a multi-processor machine).  Therefore the explicit memory barrier is unnecessary; the `volatile` is already accomplishing what you need.

Comment: @BrentArias The MemoryBarrier *is* necessary because it is possible for the processor to update the value on one processor and not on the other so one thread reads an updated value and the other thread reads a stale value.

Answer (score 5):

The book is **correct**.
The CLR's memory model indicates that load and store operations may be reordered. This goes for volatile *and* non-volatile variables.

Declaring a variable as `volatile` only means that load operations will have *acquire* semantics, and store operations will have *release* semantics. Also, the compiler will avoid performing certain optimizations that relay on the fact that the variable is accessed in a serialized, single-threaded fashion (e.g. hoisting load/stores out of loops).

Using the `volatile` keyword alone doesn't create critical sections, and it doesn't cause threads to magically synchronize with each other.

You should be **extremely** careful when you write lock free code. There's nothing simple about it, and even the experts have trouble to get it right.
Whatever is the original problem you're trying to solve, it's likely that there's a much more reasonable way to do it.

Comment: @Liran: I knew that using the volatile alone doesn't creat critical sections nor causeing thread to be synchronize with each others.. I am just asking for the _foo variable to be must updated value when any thread ask for it at any time within lock free code.

Comment: @Jalal, declaring the variable as volatile will guarantee that every load operation will read the most updated value of the variable (e.g. from the main memory instead of a register). You shouldn't spread memory barriers all over your code... doing so could have a major negative effect on performance. Again, if you're not just trying to play around and experiment with lock free code, and there's real, production code in the picture... I encourage you to find another solution.

Comment: @Liran; "declaring the variable as volatile will guarantee that every load operation will read the most updated value of the variable"; will as I understood from the book http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx that wirte follwed by read maybe not get the most updated value, and yes I am trying to experiment with lock free code; the question is: is it a big negative effect on performance of the application when do a `Thread.MemoryBarrier` before any get operation of the volatile variable,if it not I could put it in a property before any get of the variable. please see the question update

Comment: @Jalal, a store operation, followed by a read operation may be reordered if there's no data dependency between the operations (e.g. a load to X, and store to Y). Make sure you understand the CLR's memory model. Joe Duffy did a good job summarizing the rules: http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2007/11/10/CLR20MemoryModel.aspx  ... Also, the fact that you use a property has nothing to do with your code's thread safety.

Comment: @Liran: Thanks for the link I will read it for sure.. the property here is not for thread safety but it is for a freshness gurintee of the value when requested, If the value by using `volatile` is gurinteed to be alwayes fresh no matter of any thing then that is great, but if it not and no problem with `Thread.MemoryBarrier()` then way not use it in property?

Comment: @Jalal, using a property doesn't effect the "freshness" of data in any way. A property just acts as a getter/setter method. If you don't need a full fence (Thread.MemoryBarrier), don't use it. You will just suffer from a needless performance penalty. Before continuing, make sure you understand what's a memory model, what are acquire/release semantics, fences etc.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example, you would need to also put a `Thread.MemoryBarrier();` inside the loop, to make sure you get the most recent value every time you check the loop condition.

Comment: if this fixed the problem then putting Thread.MemoryBarrier() should be at the last line before close bracket of the while loop and before the call of the while loop..

Comment: @Jalal: I'm fairly certain that the explicit `MemoryBarrier` calls aren't required in these examples, so long as `_foo` is marked as `volatile`. (I'm no expert though; I'd probably just use a `lock`.)

Comment: In this case: the use of Thread.MemoryBarrier, whether before, after, or both, is not achieving anything that volatile was not already achieving.

Answer (score 1):

Pulled from [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx)...

```
class Foo
{
  int _answer;
  bool _complete;

  void A()
  {
    _answer = 123;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 1
    _complete = true;
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 2
  }

  void B()
  {
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();    // Barrier 3
    if (_complete)
    {
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();       // Barrier 4
      Console.WriteLine (_answer);
    }
  }
}
```

> Barriers 1 and 4 prevent this example
>   from writing “0”. Barriers 2 and 3
>   provide a freshness guarantee: they
>   ensure that if B ran after A, reading
>   _complete would evaluate to true.

So if we go back to your looping example...this is how it should look...

```
private void A()
{
    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    while (_someOtherConditions && _foo)
    {
        //do somthing
        Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Aaron Thanks I check that link before it is at the same book "C# 4.0 in a Nutshell".. however if this fixed the problem then putting Thread.MemoryBarrier() should be at the last line before close bracket of the while loop.

Comment: @Jalal It depends what your "do something" does, where the ThreadBarrier sits now affects your _someOtherconditions/_foo vars

Comment: @Aaron: If `_foo` is marked as `volatile` then I'm pretty sure that the explicit `MemoryBarrier` calls are unnecessary in these particular examples. (Pretty sure but not 100% sure, and if in doubt then I'd probably just use a `lock`.)

Comment: @Aaron: because the loop has to change the conditions the barrier should be the last thing in the loop.

Comment: @Henk Are you referring to the vars being used as the conditionals when you say "has to change conditions"?

Comment: Yes. And i formulated that wrong, the conditions change during the loop. So you want the barrier as late as possible.

Comment: @Henk Makes sense. I still think it can depend on what "do something" does, as if it were something IO intensive you would not want to 'lock' that long, especially if it can be done outside the barrier without any consequences. Ran into issue before where overuse of lock was used and it became a problem...

Comment: "would not want to 'lock' that long" ??? A memoryBarrier call is a momentary thing, there is no locking or other state involved. It's more like flushing the pipes.

Comment: @Henk Thanks for the correction, my misunderstanding of MemoryBarrier and it's comparison to lock

Comment: @Aaron: the link you provided deals with re-ordering issues.  The poster's code example does not exhibit any re-ordering issues.  All the poster needs is for the value of _foo to be read/written directly to memory instead of a register.  The `volatile` keyword is sufficient for that all by itself.

Comment: @Brent The link speaks about threading in general. It touches on MemoryBarrier and volatile alike, which is what the OP was questioning.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's own words on memory barriers:

MemoryBarrier is required only on multiprocessor systems with weak memory ordering (for example, a system employing multiple Intel Itanium processors).

**For most purposes, the C# lock statement, the Visual Basic SyncLock statement, or the Monitor class provide easier ways to synchronize data.**

Comment: Please refer to http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx to see that the Microsoft's own words is not correct!!.

Comment: The poster is specifically asking for a lock-free implementation.