# Boolean property in a multithreaded scenario

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In a multithreaded scenario does it make sense to declare a boolean property of a class that is read and set by many threads simultaneously in the following way in C# .net?

```cs
public class MyClass 
{
    private long _check;

    public bool Check 
    {
        get => Interlocked.Read(ref _check) == 1;
        set => Interlocked.Exchange(ref _check, Convert.ToInt64(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes (you don't need a `long` though)

Comment: The answer depends on the scenario... Is it a problem if multiple threads set the value to true at the same time ? What are you trying to protect you from ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of a volatile `bool` field is overly complex. You can achieve exactly the same thing like this:

```
private bool _check;

public bool Check
{
    get => Volatile.Read(ref _check);
    set => Volatile.Write(ref _check, value);
}
```

...or even simpler like this:

```
public volatile bool Check;
```

The `Interlocked.Exchange` is preferable to the `Volatile.Write` only when you want to get the previous value as an atomic operation. Otherwise the `Volatile.Write` [has the same effect and it's more lightweight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425738/difference-between-interlocked-exchange-and-volatile-write).

Whether having such a field is a good idea in the first place, depends on the scenario. If you have a loop and you want to use the field as a breaking mechanism, it might be a good idea. If you want to synchronize the access to some other shared state of your class, it's probably not.