# Interlocked.Exchange influence on following instructions

Tags: c#, locking, memory-barriers, lock-free, interlocked

If thread 1 runs:

```
this.Field.Flag = false;

...

var oldValue = Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.Field, newValue);
oldValue.Flag = true;
```

and thread 2 sees `oldValue.Flag == true`, is it guaranteed that it also sees `this.Field == newValue` even if it doesn't use Interlocked/Volatile to read `this.Field`?

i.e. is it guaranteed that the effects of instructions after Interlocked.Exchange are only visible after the effects of Interlocked.Exchange are themselves visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not guaranteed that a reader using plain (non-`Volatile`) loads will see `this.Field == newValue` after seeing `oldValue.Flag == true`.  Load reordering is possible.

---

Interlocked.Exchange [is a full barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71002288/224132) tied to the exchange (like x86 `lock xchg [mem]`), so yes, it guarantees order of stores on opposite sides becoming globally visible (i.e. committing to coherent L1d cache), preserving that StoreStore ordering.  (Along with enforcing [StoreLoad, LoadLoad, and LoadStore ordering](https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/).)

It appears that Interlocked operations are so strong that at least in practice, current compilers for AArch64 use `ldaxr`/`stlxr` (like a C++ `seq_cst` operation) for the exchange, and *then* do a `dmb ish` full barrier afterward.  So later stores are ordered after the store side of the exchange itself, even only weakly ordered ISAs where that costs extra barriers.  Your code depends on that, not on operations before vs. after `Interlocked.Exchange`; storing `this.Field.Flag = false;` was a red herring.

---

**But the reader has to make sure its loads are ordered wrt. each other, which doesn't happen without `Volatile.Read` or something stronger**.  Otherwise the load of `this.Field` might hit in cache and read a value from before either store became visible, while the earlier load of `oldValue.Flag` might miss in cache and only get the later value, just for an example of one possible mechanism [for LoadLoad reordering at run time](https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/) on a weakly-ordered ISA like AArch64.

Compile-time reordering is also possible in the reader, and the only way for this to go wrong on x86-64, where the hardware memory model only allows StoreLoad reordering.  (Program order + a store buffer with store-forwarding.)

In other words, you have release semantics for the writer side (`fence`;`oldValue.Flag=...` is at least as strong as `Volatile.Write` on `oldValue.Flag`), but you don't get any guarantees if you don't use an acquire load which will synchronize with it if it sees the value.  https://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/

---

BTW, your example seems weird to me.  You have `var oldValue = Interlocked.Exchange(...)` inside a function being run by one of the threads.  So it's a local variable.  How does another thread even see it at all?  Is it a reference to something other threads can already see?  And won't writing a value to `oldValue` itself maybe make `oldValue.Flag == true` before the assignment?  But the initializer value isn't available until after `Interlocked.Exchange` returns, so that's probably fine.

I'm just assuming we're talking about stores to two different objects on opposite sides of an `Interlocked.Exchange`, and a reader that reads them both without any `Volatile.Read` or `Interlocked.` operations which are full fences.

(I don't know much C# other than its memory-ordering semantics, which are kind of fun because they're documented in terms of ordering a thread's accesses to cache-coherent shared memory, unlike C++'s formalism which is defined only in terms of creating happens-before relationships and modification orders.  C#'s lock-free atomic semantics even seem to have grown out of MS's x86-centric history, like all `Interlocked.` RMWs being full barriers, like is unavoidable on x86 but costs extra on other ISAs.  Some of the underlying ordering concepts are pretty universal at a hardware level, except for strongly-ordered x86 being a lot simpler, with different languages exposing different abstractions for it.)

Comment: I don't know the reasons for the downvote, but my guess is because the answer starts with "Yes". The answer assumes that the reader's loads are ordered, although the OP has stated explicitly that they don't use `Interlocked`/`Volatile` to read `this.Field`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: The *question* assumes that, my answer doesn't. That's why I bolded the start of the 2nd paragraph, because load ordering is also necessary for any guarantee about what the reader reads.  But that wasn't the only question the OP asked, they also asked if the stores are ordered, and the answer to that last paragraph of the question is "yes". Unlike C++, C# *does* talk about store ordering on its own, even in the absence of any readers, which in hardware corresponds to order of commit from the store buffer to cache. If someone downvoted without understanding that, their loss :/

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: On 2nd look, the code depends on the Interlocked.Exchange store itself being ordered before later relaxed stores, not just on ops before the Exchange.  So the question becomes whether the stand-alone barrier comes before or after the `seq_cst` LL/SC retry loop on weakly-ordered ISAs like AArch64.  Apparently it's after, at least in the MSVC equivalent; I should probably check Sharplab for a C# version, except they only have x86 support.

Comment: @PeterCordes oldValue is a local variable, but it is a reference to the previous value of this.Field as per Interlocked.Exchange, so another thread can also access that object via the this.Field reference, thus seeing the Flag = true update if the change of this.FIeld to newValue wasn't propagated yet. I use oldValue to represent the actual object here, not the local variable holding the reference to it, i.e. thread 2 would access the same memory position as pointed by oldValue but via this.Field, so effectively for it the outcome would be this.Field.Flag == true, where this.Field == oldValue.