# Timing of memory caches coherency after memory barrier and after Interlocked operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, caching, memory-barriers, interlocked

Is there a difference in timing of memory caches coherency (or "flushing") after Interlocked operations and after invoking Memory barriers? Let's consider in C# - using any Interlocked operations vs Thread.MemoryBarrier() - is the resulting memory caches refresh behavior identical or not?

I believe there is a difference. I was solving one business case that seemed to be caused by delayed flush after memory barrier (we replaced with Interlocked operation). Also there is quite a few information sources (including [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)) suggesting that memory barriers doesn't guarantee timing of operations.

I can link more references or add example code snippet if interested, but initially I want to keep the question short (as I was down-voted for too much info in my [original question to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726904/memory-barrier-vs-interlocked-impact-on-memory-caches-coherency-timing))

Answer (score 0):

As answered also in the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726904/memory-barrier-vs-interlocked-impact-on-memory-caches-coherency-timing/27002849#27002849): CAS (Interlocked) operations have been (and most likely will be) the quickest caches flusher.